# CSS button size inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with an html page. I have created CSS buttons and placed them inside divs (rows), whose behavior should act like a table. I want each button size to be, let's say, 60% of the height and the width of the div "cells". However, they are always filling up space to the maximum size.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/User001/MkaF7/).

And here is my CSS code:

```
html,body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.container
{
    display: table;
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row
{
    width: 99%;
    height: 33%;
    //display: table;
    display: table-row;
    table-layout: fixed;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.row span
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.row span a
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.button
{
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='orange', endColorstr='orange',GradientType=0);
    background-color: orange;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px orange;
}

.button:hover
{
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfbf91', endColorstr='#dfd691',GradientType=0);
    background-color: yellow;
}

.button:active
{
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

I got stuck looking for a solution to the problem, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your explanation for the expected behavior isn't clear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The divs form a table with 3 rows and 3 cells, right? Inside these "cells" I only have link buttons. I want each button to have 60% of the size of the height and the width of the respective cell. Said otherwise, the links have no white space around them. Neither on top/bottom, neither on left/right. That's why I thought  taking a value of 60% will resize each button. I hope it's more clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

Just add a media query to the css.... I have added an example below...

```
html,body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.container
{
    display: table;
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row
{
    width: 99%;
    height: 30%;
    //display: table;
    display: table-row;
    table-layout: fixed;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.row span
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top:5%;
}

.row span a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 3%;
}

.button
{
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='orange', endColorstr='orange',GradientType=0);
    background-color: orange;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px orange;
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) 
        {
            .button
{
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='orange', endColorstr='orange',GradientType=0);
    background-color: orange;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px orange;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}            
        }

.button:hover
{
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfbf91', endColorstr='#dfd691',GradientType=0);
    background-color: yellow;
}

.button:active
{
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This only gives me 60% height. I want 60% width for each button as well.

Comment: This CSS is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I have only one more request. This works like a charm when the text in the button is short. However, if I have longer text, it will be displayed outside the button when resizing the window. Could you give me a fix for that as well? I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change the row.span property in your css it is set to 100%

Answer (score 0):

## HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="buttonPanel" class="container">
        <div id="row1" class="row">

                <a href="#" class="button">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="button">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#" class="button">Link 3</a>

        </div>
        <div id="row2" class="row">

                <a href="#" class="button">Link 4</a>
                <a href="#" class="button">Link 5</a>
                <a href="#" class="button">Link 6</a>

        </div>
        <div id="row3" class="row">

                <a href="#" class="button">Link 7</a>
                <a href="#" class="button">Link 8</a>
                <a href="#" class="button">Link 9</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

## CSS

```
 html,body
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: blue;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .container
    {
        display: table;
        width: 80%;
        height: 70%;
        position: relative;
        background: white;
        -moz-border-radius: 25px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .row
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 36%;
    }

    .row span
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    .row  a
    {
        display: inline-block;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    width: 32.7%;
    height: 70%;
    vertical-align: sub;
    margin: 0px;
    }

    .button
    {
        width: 60%;
        height: 60%;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px orange;

        background-color: orange;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: black;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px orange;
    }

    .button:hover
    {

        background-color: yellow;
    }

 .button:active
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/YV9cX/